# Low latency video player on android

Tags: android, react-native, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'd like to be able to stream the video from my webcam to an Android app with a latency below 500ms, on my local network.

To capture and send the video over the network, I use ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -an -vf format=yuv420p -f mpegts  udp://192.168.1.155:5000
```

This command takes the webcam as an input, convert it and send it to a device using the mpegts protocol.
This is not a requirement, if another technique could work, I could change the way I send the video.

I am able to read the video on another PC from the local network with a latency below 500 ms, using commands like

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! video/mpegts ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false
```

or

```
mpv udp://0.0.0.0:5000 --no-cache --untimed --no-demuxer-thread --video-sync=audio --vd-lavc-threads=1
```

So it is possible to have this range of latency.
I'd like to have the same thing on Android.

Here are my tries to do that.

### Exoplayer

After looking at the different players available on Android studio, it seems like Exoplayer is the go-to choice.
I tried different options indicated in the [live-streaming](https://exoplayer.dev/live-streaming.html) documentation, but I always end up with a stream taking seconds to start and with a latency of seconds.
I tried to add a Button to seek to the default position of the windows, but it results in a loading of several seconds.

```
DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory =
                new DefaultExtractorsFactory()
                        .setTsExtractorFlags(DefaultTsPayloadReaderFactory.FLAG_IGNORE_AAC_STREAM);

        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
                .setMediaSourceFactory(
                        new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this, extractorsFactory))
                .setLoadControl(new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                        .setBufferDurationsMs(DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS, DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_MS, 200, 200)
                        .build())
                .build();
        MyPlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        // Bind the player to the view.
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        // Build the media item.
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
                .setUri(Uri.parse("udp://0.0.0.0:5000"))
                .setLiveMaxOffsetMs(500)
                .setLiveTargetOffsetMs(0)
                .setLiveMinOffsetMs(0)
                .build();
        // Set the media item to be played.
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        // Prepare the player.
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        player.prepare();
        //player.seekToDefaultPosition();
```

This [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7238) is about the same issue and the conclusion was that Exoplayer was not fit for this use case.

> I'll be honest, ultra low-latency like this isn't ExoPlayer's main use-case

### Vlc

Another try was to use the Vlc library.
But I was unable to have the same low latency stream as with the two previous players with Vlc.
I tried changing the preferences of Vlc to stream as fast as possible as described [here](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/cd/soft/unix/VLC-setup.html)

```
Input/Codecs -> x264 preset: ultrafast - zerolatency
Input/Codecs -> Access Module: UDP input
Input/Codecs -> Clock Jitter: 500
Audio: disable audio
```

I also tried reducing the different buffers.
However, I still have a latency of more than 1 seconds with that.

### Gstreamer

Another try was to create a react-native project to use the different players available here.
One player that seemed promising was [react-native-gstreamer](https://github.com/Kalyzee/react-native-gstreamer) because it uses gstreamer which is able to stream with low latency (gst-launch command).
But the library is now outdated.

### Question

There were other tries, but none were successful.
Is there a problem with one of my approaches ?
And if not, Is there a player on Android (that I missed) which is able to achieve low latency stream like gstream or mpv on linux ?

Comment: which latency did you achieve with above methods? 
I had to work on a similar solution using a raspberry pi + cam as 'webcam' and an android device as a viewer. 
I used a custom view and a customized h264 decoder and it works but the only 'compatible' streaming source I found is to use raspivid and nc (to build up a sort of h264 tcp stream). I can share my sources if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know a native low latency player in Android.
However you can use a `WebView` in Android Studio and use a player in the web.
With this solution I streamed the webcam of my pc to my phone (in the local network) with [livecam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livecam).
They use websockets to transmit the video frame by frame, which is not ideal. With this method I had 370 ms of latency.